# Measure of coefficients in system of polynomial equations.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Let
$$
r_1(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)-c_1\cdot s(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)=0,\\
r_2(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)-c_2\cdot s(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)=0,\\
\vdots\\
r_n(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)-c_n\cdot s(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)=0,
$$
be a system of equations, where $r_i(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ for $i=1,2,\dots,n$ and $s(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ are polynomilas over the $\mathbb{R}$. How to prove that Lebesgue measure of set of coefficients $c_1,c_2,\dots,c_n$ when system of equations has infinite solution is zero?

Any help will be appreciated . Thank  you very much.

P.S. Somebody gave me advice to use Kleiman’s transversality theorem but I cannot move with that. I have been trying to prove it for $n=2$ using Bézout's theorem but I haven't be successful, too.

Comment: This is false without some conditions on the $r_i$ and $s_i$: take $n=2$, $r_1=x^2+y^2$, $s_1=1$, and $r_2=s_2=0$ for instance. Then this has infinitely many solutions when $c_1>0$, which is not a set of finite measure. Where is this problem coming from?

Comment: Please do not ask the same question multiple times.  If you have improvements to your question, please use the edit button to make the changes.